# Form client and server side validation issue

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I am working on a form which validates client side by using "jquery validation plugin" and server side by using php.
Here is my markup

**HTML**

```
<div id="recipe-form">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-lg-9">
                <form id="recipe-submit-form" class="form-horizontal" name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">   


                <div class="row control-group onoffclass">
                <label for="recipetitle" class="col col-lg-2 control-label">Recipe Title:<sup>&#42;</sup></label>
                <div class="col col-lg-7 controls">
                <input id="recipetitle" class="input-with-feedback" name="recipetitle" data-content="Required: Minimum 10 characters long" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" title="Recipe Title" placeholder="Recipe Title" type="text" />
                <?php if($titleError != '') { ?><span class="nojserror"><?php echo $titleError;?></span><?php } ?>
                </div>
                </div> <!-- recipe title -->


                <div class="row control-group onoffclass">
                <label for="recipedesc" class="col col-lg-2 control-label">Recipe Desc:<sup>&#42;</sup></label>
                <div class="col col-lg-7 controls">
                <textarea id="recipedesc" class="input-with-feedback" name="recipedesc" data-content="Required: A Brief recipe description" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" title="Recipe Description" placeholder="Recipe Short Description"></textarea>
                <?php if($descError != '') { ?><span class="nojserror"><?php echo $descError;?></span><?php } ?>

                </div>
                </div> <!-- recipe desc -->
                <div class="row">
                <div id="submitform" class="col col-lg-10 col-offset-2">
                <button name="Submit" type="submit" id="formsubmit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Recipe</button>
                </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />

                </form>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
                if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
                //title
                if(trim($_POST['recipetitle']) === '')  {
                $titleError = 'Please enter title for your recipe.';
                $hasError = true;
                } else if (strlen(trim($_POST['recipetitle']))<= 10) {
                $titleError = 'Recipe Title is too short.';
                $hasError = true;
                } else {
                $recipetitle = trim($_POST['recipetitle']);
                }

                //desc
                if(trim($_POST['recipedesc']) === '')  {
                $descError = 'Please enter description for your recipe.';
                $hasError = true;
                } else if (strlen(trim($_POST['recipedesc']))<= 10) {
                $descError = 'Recipe description is too short.';
                $hasError = true;
                } else {
                $recipedesc = trim($_POST['recipedesc']);
                }

                }
                ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
             <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var ruleSet1 = {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
            };
            $('#recipe-submit-form').validate({
            rules: {
            recipetitle: ruleSet1,
            recipedesc: ruleSet1,
            }

            });
            });
            </script>
```

Every thing seems to work fine, the problem I am facing is, when I disable Javascript, php will show validation errors. In the same time I enable Javascript and re-submit the form. Now jquery will also show the validation errors beside php errors.
Please see screenshot to understand the issue.
[image]

Would appreciate any help on this

Regards

Comment: Why not just **NOT display (disable)** the jQuery version altogether, that way if JS is enabled or not, it will show the same error message.

Comment: do you mean disable the client side validation or only disable jquery validation errors?

Comment: Client-side is JS, server-side is PHP. Yes, I meant disable the JS altogether, or use `Shivam's` suggestion below, which could work with a bit of work.

Comment: Maybe I am missing the point, but why dont you use the same element you write your PHP error to write the Javascript error? That way you would just override what was already in the element.

Answer (score 0):

What about applying a specific error classes depending if on if `js` or `php` `error`.

```
<span class="jsError">Some Error</span>
<span class="phpError">Some Error</span>
```

In your `css` you would just hide the `js` errors.

```
.jsError {
    display:none;
}
```

In your `js`, hide `php errors` and do your normal jQuery validation there which will show only the `js errors`.

```
$(function() {
    $('.phpError').hide();

    //after doing your jsValidation show js error only
});
```

This way if js is disabled, only the `PHP` errors will appear.

Comment: As per what I suggested ;-)